Intercepting and modify API response through selenium C# specflow automation
I am working on UI automation testing project with C# xunit specflow selenium, my website can be converted into breadcrumbs display mode or in one page application mode. I have already writte down many test cases when website is in breadcrumb and they are running in parallel.
Now I want to write test cases when application is in one page mode, but I want all my test cases to run in parallel mode.
so when we load the website it checks through a API call in which format my application is currently in.(breadcrumb or one page)
now I am thinking to use proxy server and modify the response to one page application for only one page test cases, so that onepage application test cases and breadcrumbs test cases can run in parallel.
I tried using WireMock proxy server and try to intercept the api call and try to modify it.
but it is not working and every time i am getting this error.
{"Status":"No matching mapping found"}
public void NavigateToOPApplication(string url)
{

    _server = WireMockServer.Start();
    var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.AddArgument($"--proxy-server={_server.Url}");

    // Create the WebDriver instance
    _driver1 = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);

    _server
    .Given(Request.Create().WithPath("/api-endpoint").UsingGet())
    .RespondWith(WireMock.ResponseBuilders.Response.Create()
        .WithStatusCode(200)
        .WithBody(@"
        {
          ""enableOnePageApplication"": true,  // Modified to true

        }"));

    _driver1.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
}

